# Pyodbc Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') error while connecting to excel

Tags: python, excel, windows, pyodbc, python-3.10

I am attempting to use pyobdc to read data from Excel, and I keep getting the following error when attempting to connect to Excel:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

**System details:**

Python 3.10 64bit

Microsoft Excel 64-bit version

ODBC Data Sources 32 & 64 bit ( DSN : Microsoft Excel driver)

[image: DNS]

**Code:**

```
import os
import sys
import time
import pyodbc

ExcelPath=C:\Automation_Code\test\Resources\RunManager.xls   
con = ("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ="+ExcelPath+";ReadOnly = True;")
print("Opened Excel successfully")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con, autocommit=True)            
cursor= cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select * from ["+SheetName+"$] where Execute ='YES'")            
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row
```

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls) driver is available